# Materialize Floating Label Overlapping

Tags: html, css, materialize

Does anyone know how I can fix the floating label overlapping with the line of the element above it as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR7Sg.jpg

Basically I would like to lower the height of the floating label.

I have tried setting margins and a few other settings in CSS on:
.input-field label
but I had no luck.

I also tried adding line breaks but that only added space between the label and the textfield, no matter where I put them.

Edit:

```
                      <div class="col s12">
                            <br>
                            <ul class="collapsible popout blue darken-3 z-depth-2" data-collapsible="accordion">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="collapsible-header blue darken-3"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>New Body Stats Entry</div>
                                    <div class="collapsible-body input-field col s4"> <label for="arms">Arms</label><input class="center-align" id="arms" type="text"> </div>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code needed to replicate this.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Understood, I added the relevant code, I did not add the whole card-panel to avoid clutter.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Disregard, for anyone else experiencing this issue, just set a margin-top using CSS; not sure how it took me an hour to figure that out.